# Slow computation with mass flow calculation out of heat demand

Tags: simulation, modelica, dymola

I am calculating the needed mass flow from a source to heat up water from 10°C to 35°C from the heat demand at any given moment.

Introducing this model to my simulation increased the simulation time a lot!

```
model m_flow_calc
 "A simple model to calculated the primary mass flow needed to heat up space heating water "
 import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
    parameter SI.Temperature T_SHW_out = 30+273.15 "Temperature of the space heating water supply temperature";
    parameter SI.Temperature T_SHW_in = 10+273.15 "Temperature of the space heating water return temperature";                      
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput Q_demand;        
    equation 
      m_flow =-Q_demand/(4120*(T_SHW_out-T_SHW_in)); //"Calculating the primary mass flow for a given Heating demand to heat the space heating water to the set temperature"     
end m_flow_calc;
```

With the calculated mass flow a boundary draws the mass flow through a heat exchanger. The Temperature after the HEX is then carried over to another boundary that "pushes" out the same mass flow like in the first boundary.
[image]

Is there something i am missing that is slowing down the simulation?

Comment: A bit difficult to judge from the part of the model only. As long as `T_SHW_out` and `T_SHW_in` are not very similar I don't see a problem with the model itself.

Could you add (1) simulation translation statistics and (2) solver log to give some more insight?

Comment: This blog post might help? http://www.claytex.com/blog/how-can-i-make-my-models-run-faster/